# Preselecting Rows on Datatable Doesn't Work in LWC (max-row-selection=1)

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable

For some reason, programmatically selecting a single row doesn't work in my datatable. To give a little background, I'm trying to preselect the very first row in my datatable by default. I use wire to retrieve the records to display. All of that is good except when I declare the datatable as *max-row-selection=1*, the row isn't being preselected at all. With max-row-selection of 2 or more, the rows are being preselected just fine.

**HTML-Markup**

```
<div class="slds-table">
<template if:true={contacts}>
    <lightning-datatable 
        data-id="contactTable"
        data={contacts} 
        columns={columns} 
        key-field="id" 
        selected-rows={preselectedContactRow}
        **max-row-selection=1**>
    </lightning-datatable>
</template>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
@track preselectedContactRow = [];
@track contacts;

// inside the wire service

this.preselectedContactRow = this.contacts.map(record=>record.id)

// ...

console.log('Rows : ', JSON.stringify(this.preselectedContactRow)); 
// record ids are being passed to this tracked variable successfully, and may contain single or multiple record ids
```

According to this [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-datatable/documentation), my current setup above should still work..

> If max-row-selection is set to a value less than the number of selected rows, only the specified number of rows will be selected. For example, if you set max-row-selection to 2 and pass in ['a', 'b', 'c'] to selected-rows, only rows a and b will be selected.

I've already tried the following:

```
// a. JS timing events didn't work

setTimeout(() => this.preselectedContactRow = this.contacts.map(record=>record.id));

// b. Passing a list to @track variable didn't work

let c_ids = [];
if(this.contacts){
   for (let i = 0; i < this.contacts.length; i++){
        c_ids.push(this.contacts.Id);
   }
   this.preselectedContactRow = c_ids;
}

// c. No, even with just one id still didn't work

this.preselectedContactRow = [...this.contacts].map((record, index) => {
   if(index == 0){
       return record.id;
   }
});

// d. Even passing a hardcoded id of a record that I know will appear in the datatable didn't work

this.preselectedContactRow = ['0011e00000xxxxxxxx'];
```

**Problem:** The @track variable for selected-rows will contain an id, but the row will never be preselected in the datatable.

**Question:** Given all that I've tried above, in regards to single row selection in lightning datatable, what's the correct or best way to preselect a record programmatically?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was due to the fact that the selected-rows were assigned yet my datatable is yet to render. In my case, I was using modals and my datatable shows up in the second modal. When moving to the modal showing the datatable, I simply needed to call `this.preselectedContactRow = this.contacts.map(record=>record.id));` in the *on click next* event again.

Comment: Can you post your full solution? I'm struggling with a similar issue.